# Nesting in emotion using css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I've the following JSX structure.

```
<div css={content} style={{ minHeight: props.minHeight }}>
  <p css={description}>{props.description}</p>
</div>
```

Now I need to write a style which will change the background of `description` when `content` is hovered. How to write that in emotion using css object.

I've tried doing this. But it didn't work.

```
const description = css({
  background: 'yellow'
})

const content = css({
  '&:hover': {
     [description]: {
        background: 'red',
     },
   },
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can import css file in your component file and add `className` to your description tag. It will work as same. I don't know there is a `css prop` in `reactjs`. Can you tell me the docs link?

Comment: Hey Kumar, I appreciate your answer but it is not relevant here :( I'm using [Emotion JS](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) for styling. You can read about it.

Comment: oh, I don't know about that. I need to learn that.

Answer (score 2):

##### Options:

###### 1. Use styled component

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const StyledP = styled.p``

const descriptionCss = css`
  background: yellow;
`

const contentCss = css`
  &:hover ${StyledP} {
     background: red;
  }
`

return (
  <div css={contentCss} style={{ minHeight: props.minHeight }}> 
    <StyledP css={descriptionCss}>{props.description}</p>
  </div>
)
```

###### 2. Reference to custom className.

```
const contentCss = css`
  &:hover .custom-class-for-some-div {
     background: red;
  }
`
```

Comment: thank you for reminding that we need to use interpolation when nesting inside another emotion selector

Comment: is `.css-` an official api? is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Vic It worked, but I never use it and I don't recommend it for you. I updated answer, where I removed this option.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the content css object has no reference as to what 'description' is. What you can do is reference the descriptions paragraph tag like so:

```
const description = css({
  background: 'yellow',
});

const content = css({
  '&:hover': {
    p: {
      background: 'red',
    },
  },
});
```